# How can I create a navigation menu in the sidebar that can also act like a slider?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, menus, navigation, plugin-recommendation

I am trying to create a page with a series of lesson/tutorial and looking to have something like a menu on the right/left side bar so the access to the topics are easier. Something like in the page

https://www.wpkube.com/ - "The best of wpkube" widget in the sidebar.

Is there a plugin that can do this job?

[image: This menu shows on all pages accessed from the menu]

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have a difficult time trying to find a plugin that offer this exact functionality. IMHO, I'm guessing you will need to develop this on your own, or hire a developer.

If you want to build it yourself, I can recommend a few resources to get you started. [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/api/) is an excellent slider that I often use, and there are a number of ways to associate your list of "lessons" with your course/tutorial.  A plugin such as [Advanced Custom Fields](https://advancedcustomfields.com) would be great for this.